# How can use less of memory on the all page, in android?

Tags: android, memory

One page of the application use of many picture. This page don't show in mobile that have low memory. how can show this page in that phones. I guess should be use that cache but don't know how.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rb.musalla.Goals_Activity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:src="@drawable/ideas" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="text 1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="time 1" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="text 2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="time 2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/getting_land" />
            </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In addition, I live in Iran and can not use sites (like developer.android.com) because of boycott USA. Please write the solution or use of site don't be problem for my country.

Comment: You can use proxy or VPN in order to access Google Official documentation.

Comment: I have VPN (Psiphon) but don't work good and don't show site yet. @CopsOnRoad

Comment: Use IP addresses of locations like US, Canada. It should work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, many images on one screen can cause memory issues if the images are not subsampled. It does not make sense to display a big image on a small screen, therefore, shrink the images using subsampling:

The basic steps in loading a large bitmap are:

- Determine the required size (from a known size or determining the size of the target View)
- Use the **BitmapFactory** class to get the bitmap’s size (set **inJustDecodeBounds** in **BitmapFactory.Options** to true)
- Calculate the subsampling value and pass it to the **BitmapFactory.Options** setting **inSampleSize**
- Use the **BitmapFactory** to load a reduced size bitmap

More detail here: [Android Bitmap Loading for Efficient Memory Usage](https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-bitmap-loading)